# Incoming https traffic blocked by Windows firewall rule Query User

Tags: windows, firewall, https

I have an Apache web server running under wsl on Windows 10. It was previously working without any issues. It was now some time since I used it and when I tested it now the Windows firewall was blocking the https requests. It is the "Public profile" on the firewall that is being used for my scenario.
I did some troubleshooting and it seems like the firewall rule that is blocking the calls is named "Query user". After some googling I understand that this rule is not visible in the Windows firewall and that it is used to query the user to accept the connections, but seem to do so only in some scenarios.

How can I make this rule accept my incoming https requests?
Any thoughts are appreciated!

My current no so good workaround is to set the public profile setting for Incoming connections to Accept, instead of the default "Block (default)" (Not to be confused with "Block all connections").

Here is an event showing the blocked call.

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
        <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-a5ba-3e3b0328c30d}"/>
        <EventID>5157</EventID>
        <Version>1</Version>
        <Level>0</Level>
        <Task>12810</Task>
        <Opcode>0</Opcode>
        <Keywords>0x8010000000000000</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-09-21T09:08:01.8655962Z"/>
        <EventRecordID>1494306</EventRecordID>
        <Correlation/>
        <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="12808"/>
        <Channel>Security</Channel>
        <Computer>JM-SERVER</Computer>
        <Security/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data Name="ProcessID">7088</Data>
        <Data Name="Application">\device\harddiskvolume1\users\jeremia\appdata\local\packages\canonicalgrouplimited.ubuntuonwindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\localstate\rootfs\usr\sbin\apache2</Data>
        <Data Name="Direction">%%14592</Data>
        <Data Name="SourceAddress">83.254.163.182</Data>
        <Data Name="SourcePort">54569</Data>
        <Data Name="DestAddress">192.168.0.110</Data>
        <Data Name="DestPort">443</Data>
        <Data Name="Protocol">6</Data>
        <Data Name="FilterRTID">1982809</Data>
        <Data Name="LayerName">%%14610</Data>
        <Data Name="LayerRTID">44</Data>
        <Data Name="RemoteUserID">S-1-0-0</Data>
        <Data Name="RemoteMachineID">S-1-0-0</Data>
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

And the corresponding firewall filter from wfpstate.xml:

```
<item>
    <filterKey>{99ef2f5f-ee43-402c-9ab0-14fd61a04dc9}</filterKey>
    <displayData>
        <name>Query User</name>
        <description>Prompt the User for a decision corresponding this Inbound Traffic</description>
    </displayData>
    <flags/>
    <providerKey>FWPM_PROVIDER_MPSSVC_WF</providerKey>
    <providerData>
        <data>6246050000000000</data>
        <asString>bF......</asString>
    </providerData>
    <layerKey>FWPM_LAYER_ALE_AUTH_RECV_ACCEPT_V4</layerKey>
    <subLayerKey>FWPM_SUBLAYER_MPSSVC_WF</subLayerKey>
    <weight>
        <type>FWP_UINT8</type>
        <uint8>8</uint8>
    </weight>
    <filterCondition numItems="1">
        <item>
            <fieldKey>FWPM_CONDITION_ORIGINAL_PROFILE_ID</fieldKey>
            <matchType>FWP_MATCH_EQUAL</matchType>
            <conditionValue>
                <type>FWP_UINT32</type>
                <uint32>1</uint32>
            </conditionValue>
        </item>
    </filterCondition>
    <action>
        <type>FWP_ACTION_BLOCK</type>
        <filterType/>
    </action>
    <rawContext>0</rawContext>
    <reserved/>
    <filterId>1982809</filterId>
    <effectiveWeight>
        <type>FWP_UINT64</type>
        <uint64>9223372036854783488</uint64>
    </effectiveWeight>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just solved this exact problem after days of troubleshooting a firewall that wasn't accepting traffic on ports that already had explicit allow rules created. Hopefully this solves the same problem for someone else.

- Tried resetting the firewall (after exporting) to no avail
- Tried deleting the registry keys for the "Query User" firewall rules as recommended by Ben N here - https://superuser.com/questions/1154812/how-to-re-trigger-windows-firewall-has-blocked-message
- Tried enabling notifications as suggested by i3v here - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2cd7bb33-aa58-4358-9503-640210c5b556/firewall-quotquery-userquot-filters-not-querying-user
- After these steps, the logs showed instead "Query User Default", but didn't fix the issue

But in the end, the problem was solved by re-creating the firewall rules with a domain account vs the local administrator account.

Comment: I found that I had to add the firewall rules in Group Policy for them to work, which I guess is a bit like creating them with a domain account?